# CircleCIでの自動デプロイが反映されず、Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:というエラーがでてしまう

Tags: laravel, circleci

GithubにプッシュしてCircleCIで自動デプロイをしたときに正常にビルドは完了しましたが以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -t webapp@${HOST_NAME} "cd laravel && \
  git pull origin master && \
  composer install -n --no-dev --prefer-dist && \
  npm ci && \
  npm run prod && \
  php artisan migrate --force && \
  php artisan config:cache"
Warning: Permanently added '*************' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
^@^@remote: Enumerating objects: 29, done.        
remote: Counting objects: 100% (29/29), done.        
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.        
remote: Total 17 (delta 10), reused 16 (delta 10), pack-reused 0        
Unpacking objects: 100% (17/17), done.                                          
From github.com:Tikka710/Laravel-ci
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   a935525..4dbc765  master     -> origin/master
Updating c4b465a..4dbc765
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    composer.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
Connection to ************* closed.

Exited with code exit status 1
```

composer.jsonがコミットできていないという事だと思いますが。どのようにすれば解決しますでしょうか？

Comment: ローカル（ここでいうとHOST_NAMEサーバ上）のcomposer.jsonが変わってしまっているようですが、何か中身を変更しましたか

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。いえ、特に変更してないです。Githubのリモートリポジトリのcomposer.jsonとローカルのを見比べても全く同じです

Comment: サーバ上のディレクトリでgit status　や git diff　とコマンドを打つと実際の違いが確認できます。例えば改行コードだったり空白文字など目に見えないものも違いが出てきます。これらで確認しても一緒ですか？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。$ git diffと打った場合何も表示されず、git statusと打った場合On branch develop nothing to commit, working tree cleanと出ます。ちなみに、デプロイ時のエラーが出たときにはgit add  .でディレクトリ以下のコードをすべてaddしてcommitをしました。

Comment: develop？masterブランチをpullしているんですよね？もう一度確認しますが、ここでいうローカルとは手元の開発作業をしたところではなくて、デプロイを実行しようとしているサーバ上のローカルを指しています。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。すいません勘違いしていました。AWSのEC2内のコードで実行したらcomposer.jsonにひとつ変更がありました。この変更されているところをローカルのcomposer.jsonで変更したいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

もっとも大事なことはgit pull をソース展開の手順とするのであれば、
本番環境の修正は直接行ってはいけない運用を徹底する必要があります。
どんなデプロイ手順でもそうですが、正規以外のデプロイ手順を取るとアプリは壊れてそれが障害につながります。
これが自動化CI/CDの基本になりますので注意しましょう。

今回の戻し方については
git pullを利用してソースの更新を実行しようとしていらっしゃいますが、
リモートのサーバのファイルに修正がありpullが実行されないものと思います。

gitの履歴とコンフリクトが起きる可能性がある修正がある状態で、pullしようとすると該当のエラーが発生します。
gitで管理している以上はその歴史（コミット修正）とは違う修正の歴史があるとコンフリクトが起こるのでマージ作業が必要です。

ただ今回の場合は本番環境でコンフリクトが起きてしまっているので、本番環境でマージを直そうとすると一時的にアプリが動かなくなる可能性があるので手順としては

（１）一旦本番で行った修正をgitに取り込む。
（２）本番の修正を戻してgitの現在いるコミットと同じ状態にする
（３）もう一度履歴を取り込む
という作業が必要です。

もともとAというコミットにいたとすると
今回の開発修正でBが修正されたとしましょう。

A→B

しかしながら本番を修正してしまって
いつの間にかCの状態になっているのです。
A→C

そこでまず（１）の作業でCの修正をBのコミットに追加します。
A→B→C´
ここで注意点はC´（ダッシュ）なのでCの修正ではないのです。
なのでこのままマージしようとしてもコンフリクトが起こります。

なので（２）の作業で本番環境をAに戻します。
これはgit resetかもし修正をしてcommitをしていないのであればgit checkoutでファイルを戻すことができます。
ただ戻す場合は本番環境のソースを一時的に修正することになるのでその動作をしてアプリが問題なく動くか確認しておく必要があります。

最後に（３）の作業で改めてgit pullを実行します。
ここまでくれば新しいアプリが展開できるでしょう

Comment: 懇切丁寧にありがとうございます。提示された手順で修正しようと思います。現時点でCircleCIとGitについての知識が不足していることを痛感しました。

Comment: gitはあくまでブランチ開発のためのツールなのでデプロイには若干不向きです。git exportでソースを出力するだけにしておいてソースの切り替え等のビルド&デプロイ作業は通常のコマンド(cpとかrsync)でやったほうがいいこともあります。

Comment: またこちらを参考にしてください。「[回答がついたら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)」ありがとうというコメントは不要です