# CircleCIでのデプロイジョブでエラーが出てしまう。

Tags: laravel, circleci

[この質問の続きです](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/73151/circleci%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E8%87%AA%E5%8B%95%E3%83%87%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%A4%E3%81%8C%E5%8F%8D%E6%98%A0%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9A-your-local-changes-to-the-following-files-would-be-overwr?noredirect=1#comment81250_73151)

EC2状のディレクトリでcomposer.jsonが変更されていたので、ローカルのcomposer.jsonを変更しgit pushをしても変わりませんでした。
EC2でブランチを切ってコミットしてもいいのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Laravel Framework 6.18.20

**エラー**

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -t webapp@${HOST_NAME} "cd laravel && \
  git pull origin master && \
  composer install -n --no-dev --prefer-dist && \
  npm ci && \
  npm run prod && \
  php artisan migrate --force && \
  php artisan config:cache"
Warning: Permanently added '*************' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
^@^@remote: Enumerating objects: 6, done.        
remote: Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.        
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.        
remote: Total 4 (delta 2), reused 3 (delta 2), pack-reused 0        
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.                                            
From github.com:Tikka710/Laravel-ci
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   4dbc765..b10d239  master     -> origin/master
Updating c4b465a..b10d239
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    composer.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
Connection to ************* closed.

Exited with code exit status 1
```

Comment: これは前の質問と何が異なるのでしょうか？ https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/73151/circleci%e3%81%a7%e3%81%ae%e8%87%aa%e5%8b%95%e3%83%87%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%82%a4%e3%81%8c%e5%8f%8d%e6%98%a0%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%81%9a-your-local-changes-to-the-following-files-would-be-overwr

Answer (score 0):

Gitのログらしきものが出ています

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    composer.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
```

リモートの `composer.json` に何か変更があるようです。

`git pull origin master` の前に `git reset HEAD --hard` するなどすればとりあえず解決しそうな気はします。

Comment: Git reset は本来変更しては行けないファイルを変更してしまう危険が伴います。必ず目視で変更していいファイルかどうか確認してから行った方がいいです。

Comment: 特に今回みたいに厳密なリポジトリ運用がされていないケースは本番だけ修正されてしまっていると、ロールバックが起こりがちです。本来は本番ファイルの修正はデプロイ以外では行わないことが大事なんですけど。

Comment: 質問者の環境によりますよね、見た感じ練習なのかと思ってました